# Text & Icons are blurry and not obvious in iOS when using arabic language [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Text & Icons are blurry and not obvious in iOS when using arabic language in Xamarin Forms

**Page in Arabic:**

[image]

**Page in English:**

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide some more informations about your problem and what you've done so far.

Comment: Hi, it's a strange phenomenon, and which version of xamarin forms and visual studio used is .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Xamarin.Forms (4.2.0.848062)

Comment: @MennaMagdy Okey , could you share a sample project here if have time , I will check it in my local environment .